# Scala Quill incorrect parses when two level Option Embedded classes

Tags: scala, quill.io

Quill does not parse embedded option class if it's two-level option embedded class is None

**Version**: `3.4.10`
**Module**: `quill-jdbc-monix`
**Database**: `postgresql`

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

I have the next classes:

```
case class Customer(id: String, personData: Option[PersonData] = None)
case class PersonData(firstName: String, address: Option[Address] = None) extends Embedded
case class Address(country: String, city: String) extends Embedded

run(quote {
      query[Customer]
        .filter(_.id == lift(id))
    }).map(_.headOption)
```

If all fields are filled in the database then the query works fine.
If address fields (`country, city`) are `null` in the database but person data field `firstName` is filled then the `personData` field in `Customer` is `None`.
But I expected that the `personData` should be `Some` and only `address` field in it should be `None`

Comment: It could be better if you specify `country` and `city` fields as `Option` if they are nullable in db

Comment: these fields are mandatory. If address exist then these fields should be filled

Comment: If they are mandatory, why they are nullable in database? You mentioned that "If address fields (`country`, `city`) are `null` in the database ..."

Comment: `Address` is an embedded class. These fields are mandatory in `Address`, but address whole is not mandatory in the `PersonData`, so in `Customer` too. If these fields in a database will be nullable then there will be a situation like a `personData` will have a field `address = Some(Address(None, None))`

Comment: So in `address` table these fields aren't nullabe. but in `customer` table foreign key that refers to `personData` table is nullable. Am I right?

Comment: No. In the Customer table these fields are plain. Only one table `customer` in the database with all fields. But in code `PersonData` and `Address` are `Embedded` so quill should be able to distribute these fields into to main class `Customer` and embedded classes `PersonData` and `Address`

Comment: Please describe the tables in the question